# Categorize objects in different lists depending on a property

Tags: java, list, arraylist, logic, categories

I'm having a problem in categorizing objects in different lists using the `interest` property.

I have a list of users objects as List, my user class looks like the following:

```
class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String interest;
    //constructors, getters & setters etc...
}
```

I'm trying to display users depending on a certain interest, but I feel like there's an easier way to do this other than what I've tried.

And I need the interest list to be dynamic other than using a fixed set of elements in a `switch`, And also I don't know if there is a better and more efficient way without having to use 3 `lists` a list for each interest.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
List<User> javaInterestList;
List<User> javascriptInterestList;
List<User> cInterestList;

public void category(List<User> unfilteredList) {
    for (User u : unfilteredList) {
        String interest = u.getInterest().toLowerCase();
        switch (interest) {
        case "java":
            javaInterestList.add(u);
            break;
        case "c":
            cInterestList.add(u);
            break;
        case "javascript":
            javascriptInterestList.add(u);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem in the above that I'm restricted to only 3 interests, Is there any way to solve this problem and a better, cleaner way to do it?

Comment: use a `Map<String, List<User>>`. Using streams: `Map<String, List<User>> usersByInterest = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getInterest))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing to think about here is not the mechanism of filtering, rather the used `data-structure`.

In such a situation, you are allocating different type of `users` with a certain interest (`key`). Which is a perfect use case for **maps**.

I think you just need to use a map for the following situation.

> The problem in the above that I'm restricted to only 3 interests, Is there any way to solve this problem

Of course you can categorize as many interests as you desire, take a look at the following method:

```
public static Map<String,List<User>> category(List<User> unfilteredList){
        Map<String,List<User>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(User u :unfilteredList){
            String inerest = u.getInterest();
            if(result.containsKey(u.getInterest())){
                List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(result.get(inerest));
                users.add(u);
                result.put(inerest, users);
            }else{
                List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                users.add(u);
                result.put(inerest, users);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

> Is there a better, cleaner way to do it?

Yes, using `Java 8 Streams` you can easily rewrite the above in only one line of code:

```
public static  Map<String,List<User>> category(List<User> unfilteredList){
        return unfilteredList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u.getInterest()));
    }
```

Comment: the cast `((User)u)` is redundant and you'll want to group by `u.getInterest().toLowerCase()` rather than `u.getInterest()` as that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

this is a perfect opportunity to use a `groupingBy` collector.

```
Map<String, List<User>> resultSet = 
           unfilteredList.stream().collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u.getInterest().toLowerCase());
```

now you can retrieve the list of users for a given key by doing:

```
List<User> java = resultSet.get("java");
List<User> c = resultSet.get("c");
List<User> javascript = resultSet.get("javascript");
```